# how to overload two methods with different input parameters

Tags: c#, refactoring, overriding, overloading

I have these two functions

```
private void calcResults()
{
   MakePath(id, results, _resultCount);
   MakePath(id, "XYZ", _resultSICount)
}

private string MakePath(string subFolder, object obj, int index)
{
    string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputDir, subFolder);
    string fileName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}.xml",
           obj.GetType().Name, _dateTimeSource.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT), index.ToString());
    return System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
}

private string MakePath(string subFolder, string tempFileName, int index)
{
    string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputDir, subFolder);
    string fileName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}.xml",
           tempFileName, _dateTimeSource.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT), index.ToString());
    return System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
}
```

Please can some one help.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question / problem that you are having..?

Comment: In the title, you speak about *overriding* methods, but none of the shown methods is `virtual`, so overriding is not possible in this case, anyway.

Comment: I need to first avoid redundant code.. then i want make the use of method overriding to simplify the code. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: yes.. so how can i create a virtual function in this case.. thanks

Comment: Read this article on `Method OverLoading` I think you should understand the difference between the key word `Override` vs `Overload` [Method Overloading](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/)

Comment: Thank you so much guys.. I am sorry i confused everyone..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you mean you want to overload the method to avoid code duplication... here's how I'd go about it.

```
    private void calcResults()
    {
       MakePath(id, results.GetType(), _resultCount);
       MakePath(id, "XYZ", _resultSICount)
    }

    private string MakePath(string subFolder, Type type, int index)
    {
        return MakePath(subFolder, type.Name, index);
    }

    private string MakePath(string subFolder, string tempFileName, int index)
    {
        string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputDir, subFolder);
        string fileName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}.xml",
               tempFileName, _dateTimeSource.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT), index.ToString());
        return System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
    }
```

I would avoid using object as the type for your second parameter, as it seems ambiguous in this case, using Type indicates the intended purpose of the parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. exactly what  i wanted.. I apologies for not being clear enough..

Answer (score 2):

You can think about something like this:

```
    private string MakePath(string subFolder, object obj, int index)
    {        
        //tempFileName here is created beased on the TYPE of the object passed
        string tempFileName = obj.GetType().Name;
        return MakePath(subFolder,tempFileName , index); 

    }

    private string MakePath(string subFolder, string tempFileName, int index)
    {
        //combine directory path
        string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputDir, subFolder);

        //compute final file name based on the several 
        //parameters and tempFileName parameter
        string fileName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}.xml",
            tempFileName, _dateTimeSource.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT), index.ToString());

        return System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
    }
```

Following the logic of the code presented, correct me if I'm wrong, the only difference between these 2 methos is that in first `tempFileName` is based on the *type name*, in the second, instead, it's a just a second parameter passed by the *caller*.

Comment: yes you are right.. but i wanted to make use of the overriding concept over here.. can you suggest something on that.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user175084 there is nothing to override, it seems to be all in one class. What you probably are looking for is "polymorphism", which is exactly what is in the answer.

Comment: @user175084 You mean `overloading` not `overriding`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that string is also an object, so compiler cannot choose what method to use. You can change parameter order, or rename one of the methods.

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler choose the string version for a string, because it fits better?

Comment: The compiler would choose the `string` version for a `string`, and the `object` version for anything else. No conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string MakePath(string subFolder, object obj, int index)
{
    if(obj.GetType()==typeof(string))
    {
        //copy the strong typed version to here;
        return;
    }
    string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputDir, subFolder);
    string fileName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}.xml",
        obj.GetType().Name, _dateTimeSource.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT), index.ToString());
    return System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
}
```

You can then use one function to do two jobs. Will this do?

Comment: I'd make a `string` from the `object` inside your `if` and then let control continue.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the 'results' value to an object:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var ret1 = GetValue("String");
        Console.WriteLine(ret1);
        var ret2 = GetValue((object)"test");
        Console.WriteLine(ret2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static object GetValue(string p0)
    {
        return p0;
    }

    private static object GetValue(object p0)
    {
        return "Object";
    }
}
```

Second call to GetValue get's routed to the one with the object param.